# Framework/library for producing HTML5 code

Tags: html

I have a project in which I need to create an application that enables WYSIWYG editing of HTML5 content. That is, a tool that enables you to visually edit pages by drag and drop of objects such as text, images, edit boxes, videos and such after which this page can be saved as HTML5/javaScript webpages.

There are of course commercial and free tools on the market that do this but I need to create my own tool.

Coding the entire transformation from the visual layout to the HTML5 code is a huge task obviously.

I wondered if there is a framework or such that can be used to actually create the HTML5 code. That is, my app will handle the visual aspects of the editing and calling this framework will generate the HTML5 code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### Twitter Bootstrap

This is what we use for our application in our labs, as it is free and open source. You can try [**Twitter Bootstrap**](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), Sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development.

#### From their website:

> **Bootstrap** utilizes [LESS CSS](http://lesscss.org/), is compiled via [Node](http://nodejs.org/), and is managed through [GitHub](http://github.com/) to help nerds do awesome stuff on the web. Bootstrap was made to not only look and behave great in the latest desktop browsers (as well as IE7!), but in tablet and smartphone browsers via [responsive CSS](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) as well.
>
> A 12-column responsive [grid](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#grid), dozens of components, [javascript plugins](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html), typography, form controls, and even a [web-based Customizer](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) to make Bootstrap your own.